# Calculation form returning error or blank page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a form that shows the cartesian product of 2 sets that will be given by the user.

For some reason, it's not working...

Snippet:

```js
    function cartesianProductOf() {
        return _.reduce(arguments, function(a, b) {
            return _.flatten(_.map(a, function(x) {
                return _.map(b, function(y) {
                    return x.concat([y]);
                });
            }), true);
        }, [ [] ]);
    };
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#calculate").click(function(){
    
        document.body.appendChild(form);
    
        var setone = $("#setoneinput").value;
        var settwo = $("#settwoinput").value;
    
        console.log(setone);
        console.log(settwo);
    
    
        // document.write ( cartesianProductOf($setone,$settwo) );
        console.log("Clicked");
    
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container inputs-container">
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-label-group col-sm-6 input-div">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="setoneinput" name="setone" placeholder="Set One">
      </div>
      <div class="form-label-group col-sm-6 input-div">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="settwoinput" name="settwo" placeholder="Set Two">
      </div>
      <small class="notice">Please insert a comma between each set element</small>
      <div class="form-label-group col-sm-12 calculate-button-container">
        <span formtarget="_blank" class="calculate-button" id="calculate" name="Calculate"><i class="fas fa-calculator"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Note that the js is in a different file called scripts.js

The error I'm getting is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined
>       at HTMLSpanElement. (scripts.js:14)
>       at HTMLSpanElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
>       at HTMLSpanElement.v.handle (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)

Comment: `document.body.appendChild(form)` what is `form` here?

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code

- Did not declare form variable need use `var form = document.forms[0];`
- Use wrong get value with jquery `var settwo = $("#settwoinput").value;` need change to `var settwo = $("#settwoinput").val();`

See corrected below

```js
function cartesianProductOf() {
        return _.reduce(arguments, function(a, b) {
            return _.flatten(_.map(a, function(x) {
                return _.map(b, function(y) {
                    return x.concat([y]);
                });
            }), true);
        }, [ [] ]);
    };
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var form = document.forms[0];
      $("#calculate").click(function(){
    
        document.body.appendChild(form);
    
        var setone = $("#setoneinput").val();
        var settwo = $("#settwoinput").val();
    
        console.log(setone);
        console.log(settwo);
    
    
        // document.write ( cartesianProductOf($setone,$settwo) );
        console.log("Clicked");
    
      });
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container inputs-container">
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-label-group col-sm-6 input-div">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="setoneinput" name="setone" placeholder="Set One">
      </div>
      <div class="form-label-group col-sm-6 input-div">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="settwoinput" name="settwo" placeholder="Set Two">
      </div>
      <small class="notice">Please insert a comma between each set element</small>
      <div class="form-label-group col-sm-12 calculate-button-container">
        <span formtarget="_blank" class="calculate-button" id="calculate" name="Calculate"><i class="fas fa-calculator"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```